Android Jetpack Compose, Combining LazyColumn, StickyHeader & Tablayout list breadcrumbs
I have a complex list based UI that is based around scroll events.  It's laid out in the following order
TextView
Tablayout --> Each tab is a textview of a LazyList section header 
LazyList 
    SectionHeader
        Item
        Item 
        Item
   SectionHeader 
BottomButton

The screen needs to support the following interactions

When a user selects a tab in the tablayout the LazyList scrolls to the corresponding StickHeader
When the user scrolls so that a StickyHeader section reaches the top of the screen of the LazyList; so it is the top item of the list; and the divider line at the top of the item becomes visible the tablayout needs to scroll to the corresponding section.

So I need the following capabilities.

For LazyList I need to be able to scroll to an item using the item position
For StickyHeader I need an event for when the StickyHeader reaches the top of the screen; or it replaces the StickyHeader that is currently in 'Sticking' state. I also would need to get the position that it is in the list.

Are these possible?  If you know how to do this and have any documentation please let me know!

What have you tried so far? I think your question is a bit broad.

Also please explain if the LazyListState (fromrememberLazyListState()) scroll functions solve your first problem.

Hello,  sorry for the late reply.  I was able to solve the first problem using lazyList fairly easily.  The second issue is a framework bug.  I know this because it is only reproducible when you have a section with a single item.  If all of the sections have more than one item there is no problem. It's not a size issue either; as I played around with the size of that on item; making it larger or smaller than the regular item size and it's the same problem.  I have some screencasts and I'm going to create a bug ticket with the Google Android team.

Just another update I created a custom solution using an overlay and a canvas and it's working pretty well
